# Django not creating id (pk) on save

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have an old project that I have been asked to maintain and I'm getting some very strange behavior.  I have this bit of code where a user's transaction is saved

```
    trans = Transaction(
        # id=str(newest_id),
        user=request.user,
        account=userAccount,
        # balance=balance,
        date=date,
        description=description,
        credit=credit,
        debit=debit,
        monthNum=monthNum,
        monthName=monthName,
        year=year
    )
    trans.save()  # adds record to the database
```

The problem is that the transaction saves but it isn't assigned a id or a primary key (to an sqlite3 database).  You can see by the commented code that I've even tried to force it to add an ID number but it didn't like that (and it is a horrible idea as well).  I'm pretty sure it is not the code because I'm getting the same behavior from the Admin panel.  If I create a new transaction there it saves, but when I try and access the newly created save I get the error "Transaction with ID "None" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?"

I'm thinking this has something to do with the Django version.  It was running on local machine which died.  I've been asked to get it up and running again, but there was no requirements.txt file so I am guessing which version of Django it was using. I thought it was 2.0 but it might have been even older than that.  Does anyone have any insight on what might be the cause of this?

Thanks

edit - here is the model as requested

class Transaction (models.Model):

```
# id = models.ObjectIdField(db_column="_id", primary_key=True)
# balance = models.IntegerField()
date = models.DateField()
description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
credit = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
debit = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
category = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
tag = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
monthNum = models.IntegerField()
monthName = models.CharField(max_length=10)
year = models.IntegerField()
user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
account = models.ForeignKey(BankAccounts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
exclude_value = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.user, self.description)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('transaction-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I tried manually adding the pk to it (this also didn't work) but in it's original state there was no id specified.

I also came across a post suggesting that it needed to have it specified in the settings.  This also did not work.

Comment: Can you show you're model as well? From my understanding the pk, especially the default, is an auto-incrementing integer field which means the db itself should take care of it.

Comment: Share your model, perhaps it defined the pk in it and it's different than `id`

Comment: Sorry, I should have done that.  Here is the model

Answer (score 0):

After some research, there was a function that ran some analytics on this table using pandas to read and then replace the table.  It seems that when pandas replaced the table it corrupted it somehow so when Django tried to write to the table it couldn't access the id column.